# Interior door handle with privacy lock for 2-inch thick interior doors

Tags: doorknob

I need to replace all of my interior door handles with new hardware that includes privacy locks for bathrooms and bedrooms.  All doors are the correct thickness to accept standard US replacements (Schlage, Kwickset, Baldwin, etc).

The previous owner replaced two doors with 2-inch thick ones that are too thick for the standard American lock sets.  I’ve seen a lot of thick door extension kits but they seem to be designed for exterior locksets only.

I’ve been able to find extremely expensive European-made sets, but the prices require a second mortgage.

Is it possible to extend a retail hardware store-grade interior privacy set to work on a thicker door?

Comment: "*All doors are the correct thickness*"  All except two. https://www.directdoorhardware.com/door-hardware-for-214-thick-doors.htm

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a little out-of-line, as shopping advice goes stale fast out there in the world, but do this:

- go to build.com and search "interior privacy lockset 2" door"
- in the side column, headed "Narrow Your Results", under 'function', select privacy.
- same column, under 'door thickness', select 2"
- sort low to high price and you'll find an array of decent options